# Looking for Mysql Backup/Sync suggestions (multiple servers syncing to 1)

Tags: mysql, synchronization, mysql-backup

I have 3 mysql servers that i need to backup daily.. each server uses just 1 database w/ multiple tables..

I've scripted a mysql dump script on each server.. but this time i want each mysql server backing up to a 4th server (MASTER SERVER) (w/c is remote location) ..

The Master server will serve as a MIRROR for all 3 servers, so that we can view the data of the other servers even if one of them goes down, because the Master server will be on a more reliable internet connection .

NOTES and LIMITATIONS:
1) EACH SERVER needs to "send" their backups to the MASTER SERVER, because the master server can not do "incoming" connection to each slave servers (port forwarding not supported on the slaves)

2) Prefer that only the "changes" are backed up to make things lighter on the network. (synchronization? incremental?)

3) All are running windows 7 at the moment, because for now i'm using Navicat MySQL's synchronization features.. I would prefer to use a PHP script based solution so i can migrate things to *nix..  i've read about replication and all that stuff, but I kinda wanted a ready solution, perhaps a software i could download or buy or something.. I've no time to code my own sync/replication scripts/software. just wana get over this remote sync hurdle and move on w/ the project.

regards to all

Answer (score 0):

> i've read about replication and all that stuff, but I kinda wanted a
>   ready solution

But replication is a ready-solution just type a few commands and change a few configuration.

Comment: Sorry but i meant, i dont wana deal w/ configuring that on the code level, and messing about connections and stuff.. i was kinda hoping there's a software like Navicat.. but if all else fails.. i guess ill have to deal w/ hard coding replication ..just didn't wana waste time on this part anymore though